# Why is JVM HeapMemoryUsage init value greater than commited / max value?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, heap-memory

I have an application with the options below:

```
-xms2g -xmx2g
```

I found the `init` value is greater than `max` and `commited` value.
It seems that init value contains the metaspace size. I searched the javadoc, but found no answer for this. Could you give me the code / javadoc reference for this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: VisualVM screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[getHeapMemoryUsage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#getHeapMemoryUsage()) describe init as the **setting/definition value and not the real sum**:

> The **used and committed size of the returned memory usage is the sum** of those values of all heap memory pools whereas the **init and max size of the returned memory usage represents the setting** of the heap memory which **may not be the sum** of those of all heap memory pools.

You setting is 2g which is equal to 2147483648 as your init display

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html

In the section "Method Summary", it is written that getInit() returns the amount of memory in bytes that the Java virtual machine initially requests from the operating system for memory management.

As I understood, 'init' is the requested amount of memory by JVM, which can be greater than 'max', but OS only returns the defined 'max' amount. In your case it is 2077753344 bytes.